# Object type reference variable assigned to a primitive

Tags: java, int

In java, the `int` is a primitive type and the `Integer` is an object.

```
    Integer x = 4;
```

This line of code produces no errors, even though I think it technically should if there was no special case for it. It's an object type reference variable being assigned to primitive type, which normally does not make much sense. So why does this not produce an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called [auto-boxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

The compiler will automatically box primitives when used as objects.